# Run synchronous powershell script on startup

Tags: powershell, windows-10, startup, jobs

I'm aiming to run a Powershell script on the startup on my windows 10. This tutorial has perfectly explained that: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-create-job-that-runs-at-startup/
But I expect the job to keep my script running as my app is listening to some events but when I check the status of the job using the `Get-job` cmdlet it shows that it's completed. I think that it's treating my script as an asynchronous one and eventually, my doesn't listen to anything. Any idea how can I make it synchronous i.e. keep my script running forever? This is the content of my ps1 file:

```
C:\Users\m\Desktop\Scripts\Activate.ps1
python C:\Users\m\Desktop\app.py
```

Comment: Are you sure, your script doesn't terminate? How did you make your script "run forever"? Does it run at all?

Comment: Either add transcript to the code to diagnose it further (see `Start-Transcript` command) or post your code here - there's many reasons this could be happening.

Comment: When I run `Get-job` it shows that the job is completed but I expect it to be running. Just updated the question to show the content of my ps1 file that I'm running.

Comment: The app that I'm running is listening to an API and should never end.